# Where are ghostscript options / switches documented?

Tags: command-line, pdf, ghostscript

I know there is a Ghostscript option, for instance `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` - where is that documented? How can I see what other options it accepts, appart from `screen`? Also, `-dMaxSubsetPct=100` - what does it do?

I open `man gs`, search for `PDFSET`, I get "Pattern not found". I type in a search engine, I get a myriad of personal webpages, no documentation hits.

Can anyone help with a link?

---

EDIT: also see this related post:

[Querying Ghostscript for the default options/settings of an output device (such as 'pdfwrite' or 'tiffg4') - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001107/querying-ghostscript-for-the-default-options-settings-of-an-output-device-such)

... for getting a list of supported options for a given device.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [Overview of Ghostscript](https://ghostscript.com/docs/9.54.0/Readme.htm) page, I found the
[VectorDevices.htm](https://ghostscript.com/docs/9.54.0/VectorDevices.htm) page explains `dPDFSETTINGS`:

> `-dPDFSETTINGS=`*configuration*
> Presets the "distiller parameters" to one of four predefined settings:
>
> - `/screen` selects low-resolution output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "Screen Optimized" setting.
> - `/ebook` selects medium-resolution output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "eBook" setting.
> - `/printer` selects output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "Print Optimized" setting.
> - `/prepress` selects output similar to Acrobat Distiller "Prepress Optimized" setting.
> - `/default` selects output intended to be useful across a wide variety of uses, possibly at the expense of a larger output file.

On the same page, `MaxSubsetPct` only appears in a table of recognized "Acrobat Distiller 5 parameters defined in the DistillerParameters document included in the Acrobat SDK", and links to that SDK.

Instead of downloading the large SDK, I searched for "Distiller Parameters" on Adobe's site and found [Adobe PDF Creation Settings](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/pdf_creation_apis_and_specs/PDFCreationSettings.pdf) which explains MaxSubsetPct on page 88:

> **MaxSubsetPct**
>
> **Supported by:** all applications
> **Type:** integer
> **UI name:** Subset embedded fonts when percent of characters used is less than: *value* %
> **Default value:** 100
>
> The maximum percentage of glyphs in a font that can be used before the entire font is embedded instead of a subset. The allowable range is 1 through 100.
>
> Distiller only uses this value if SubsetFonts is `true`. For example, a value of 30 means that a font will be embedded in full (not subset) if more than 30% of glyphs are used; a value of 100 means all fonts will be subset no matter how many glyphs are used (because you cannot use more than 100% of glyphs).

Comment: Many thanks for that @Bavi_H - so I should have looked for `ps2pdf` instead! Well, that didn't really occur to me, so I appreciate the pointer `:)` Cheers!

Comment: links are deadd

Answer (score 16):

To get a list of all these options supported by `-dPDFSETTINGS=...`, you can do this:

```
gs \
  -dNODISPLAY \
  -c ".distillersettings {exch ==only ( ) print ==} forall quit"
```

You should see this Result:

```
/default -dict-
/prepress -dict-
/PSL2Printer -dict-
/ebook -dict-
/screen -dict-
/printer -dict-
```

You can execute the following Ghostscript command to query for the detailed settings of the `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` parameter:

```
gs \
  -q \
  -dNODISPLAY \
  -c ".distillersettings /screen get {exch ==only ( ) print ===} forall quit" \
| sort
```

This one queries Ghostscript's internal `.distillersettings` *dictionary*, which holds a key named `/screen`, whose value again is another dictionary... The output should be something like this (may vary slightly depending on your exact Ghostscript version):

```
/AutoRotatePages /PageByPage
/CannotEmbedFontPolicy /Warning
/ColorACSImageDict << /ColorTransform 1 /QFactor 0.76 /Blend 1 /HSamples [2 1 1 2] /VSamples [2 1 1 2] >>
/ColorConversionStrategy /sRGB
/ColorImageDownsampleType /Average
/ColorImageResolution 72
/CompatibilityLevel 1.3
/CreateJobTicket false
/DoThumbnails false
/EmbedAllFonts true
/GrayACSImageDict << /ColorTransform 1 /QFactor 0.76 /Blend 1 /HSamples [2 1 1 2] /VSamples [2 1 1 2] >>
/GrayImageDownsampleType /Average
/GrayImageResolution 72
/MonoImageDownsampleType /Average
/MonoImageResolution 300
/NeverEmbed [/Courier /Courier-Bold /Courier-Oblique /Courier-BoldOblique /Helvetica /Helvetica-Bold /Helvetica-Oblique /Helvetica-BoldOblique /Times-Roman /Times-Bold /Times-Italic /Times-BoldItalic /Symbol /ZapfDingbats]
/PreserveEPSInfo false
/PreserveOPIComments false
/PreserveOverprintSettings false
/UCRandBGInfo /Remove
```

The same you can do for all the (other) parameters `-dPDFSETTINGS=...` can take:

- `/prepress`
- `/printer`
- `/default`
- `/screen`
- `/ebook`
- `/PSL2Printer`

It's quite interesting to compare the detailed settings of all these (and also look up in parallel the Documentation for [**Ps2pdf.htm**](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.05/Ps2pdf.htm#Options)...).

Comment: Suppose I want to tweak one of the parameters within the `screen` settings. How would I pass all these commands on the command line to `gs`?

Comment: @AlecJacobson: To answer your question you'd have to name which parameter you'd want to tweak.

Comment: I'm basically look for the answer to this (unanswered) question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289570/ghostscript-getting-pdfsettings-ebook-into-individual-arguments

Comment: @AlecJacobson: This doesn't help me *quickly* grasp what your problem is. *(I'm available for hiring by the hour, should that help you, though...)*

Comment: Current [doc](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Readme.htm)

Answer (score 4):

This is a good document for new users:

https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html

Comment: Many thanks for that, @nwhsvc - it looks like indeed a very good document (just gave it a quick browse), but again, it doesn't mention neither "-dPDFSETTINGS" nor "-dMaxSubsetPct", let alone explain what they do. Is there a reference that explains these? Cheers!

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following:

`ps2pdf`:

"Screen Optimized" "eBook" "Print Optimized" "Prepress Optimized"

`Acrobat 'Save as Adobe PDF' printer dialog`:

"Press Quality" "High Quality Print" "Smallest File Size" "Standard"

[Adobe PDF presets](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-conversion-settings.html#adobe_pdf_presets):

`Press Quality`

Creates PDF files for high-quality print production (for example, for digital printing or for color separations to an imagesetter or platesetter). However, it does not create files that are PDF/X compliant. In this case, the quality of the content is the highest consideration. The objective is to maintain all the information in a PDF file that a commercial printer or print service provider requires to print the document correctly. This set of options uses PDF 1.4, converts colors to CMYK, and downsamples color and grayscale images to 300 ppi and monochrome images to 1200 ppi. It embeds subsets of all fonts and preserves transparency (for file types capable of transparency).

`High Quality Print`

Creates PDFs for quality printing on desktop printers and proofing devices. This preset uses PDF 1.4, downsamples color and grayscale images to 300 ppi and monochrome images to 1200 ppi. It also embeds subsets of all fonts, leaves color unchanged, and does not flatten transparency (for file types capable of transparency).

`Smallest File Size`

Creates PDF files for displaying on the web or an intranet, or for distribution through an email system. This set of options uses compression, downsampling, and a relatively low image resolution. It converts all colors to sRGB, and (for Adobe Acrobat Distiller-based conversions) does not embed fonts. It also optimizes files for byte serving.

`Standard`

Creates PDF files to be printed to desktop printers or digital copiers, published on a CD, or sent to a client as a publishing proof. This set of options uses compression and downsampling to keep the file size down. However, it also embeds subsets of all (allowed) fonts used in the file, converts all colors to sRGB, and prints to a medium resolution. Windows font subsets are not embedded by default.

There's no exact correlation with the `ps2pdf` `PDFSETTINGS` but it at least gives an idea of the differences in preset qualities.

Comment: It should be noted that, according to the Ghostscript manual, the best quality is obtained by not specifying PDFSETTINGS; see [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/VectorDevices.htm#PSPDF_IN).