# Ghostscript's /ebook preset creating some undesired effect on PDF but /printer doesn't

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I would like to use ghostscript (version 9.27) to batch compress big quantities of pdf files. The best option for me regarding compress ratio is -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook, since it is able to reduce my files on average to about 40-50% of original size.

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=compressed.pdf original.pdf
```

Problem is that black background appears behind some text in a compressed pdf and makes it unusable. Using -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer presets does not produce this black background effect but is not an option for me since it does not compress enough.

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=compressed.pdf original.pdf
```

I did a comparison between this settings thanks to this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/435410/where-are-ghostscript-options-switches-documented) and tried tweaking specific settings but with no luck. Thank you if anybody has an idea. I will try to generate a pdf without user sensitive information which I can append. For now, these are only snips of the part of the pdf document that gets "corrupted" during compression.

[before compressing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nfvT.png) ----> [after compressing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN25y.png)

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with different settings I found out that setting ColorConversionStrategy was crucial. Using other strategies like (sRGB or Gray) helped with compression a bit, but caused these artifacts. I had to use the LeaveColorUnchanged and it worked fine.